# The iOS 8.x simulator runtime is not available

Tags: xcode, xcode7

After upgrade to the release version of Xcode 7.0, I am receiving the error message "The iOS 8.2 simulator runtime is not available."

[image]

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to download the simulator files again from within Xcode. Go to "Preferences...", then tap the "Downloads" tab.

[image]